# How to return multiple objects when passing two array arguments

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a method in java let say:

```
public List<Data> getData(String[] str, Integer[] num, String ss);
```

I have to pass two array and a non-array arguments as shown above, this method returns List of objects of type Data.

Now, the question is how to create a list of objects which contain every possible combination of elements of the array.

i.e : Object with elements :

```
getData(String[0] str, Integer[0] num, String ss);
getData(String[0] str, Integer[1] num, String ss);
getData(String[1] str, Integer[0] num, String ss);
getData(String[1] str, Integer[1] num, String ss);
```

Any clue will be appreciated.

Comment: Use nested loop. Sorry I'm not going to write you a code because this looks very much like a homework and you should be doing your research. If you ask what's nested loop then we're happy to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `List<Data>` inside your method then loop through one array

```
for (String s: str)
```

then for each element in that array, loop through the other array, this is called a [nested loop](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/Looping/NestedFor.htm)

```
for (Integer i : num)
```

Then create a `Data` object for each combination and add to a `List<Data>`

```
 for (String s: str){
    for (Integer i : num){
       //TODO Add new Data(s,i,ss) to list
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, One more condition is what if either of the two arrays are empty (having no elements).

Comment: if either is empty then the resulting data is just the non-empty array, converted to `Data` with nulls set to the other property.